# How can I profile a request in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profiling

How can I profile a controller action?

One of my views is taking quite some time to render, and I'd like to break it down. I see `script/performance/profiler`, but that seems to only have access to the global scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/) is the way to go. Here's a howto, *[How to profile your Rails and Ruby applications with ruby-prof](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/255-how-to-profile-your-rails-and-ruby-applications-with-ruby-prof)*.

If you use it in combination with a visualisation tool such as [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html), you can easily separate the code that is your application code from the framework code.

I gave a talk on these tools at my local Ruby-users group a while back: *[Making your rails app kick ass with ruby-prof and kcachegrind](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/ajax-ria/making-your-rails-app-kick-ass-with-ruby-prof-and-kcachegrind)*.

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions in the link given here, but discovered that `script/performance/request` was removed starting from Rails 2.3.2.

Comment: Yes, this answer is Rails-2 specific as I gave it in 2010. Not sure the Rails 3 way of doing this one...

Comment: Changelog (http://rails.rubyonrails.org/files/railties/CHANGELOG.html) says: Remove script/performance/request in favour of the performance integration tests. [Pratik Naik]

"To continue using script/performance/request, install the request_profiler plugin :

  script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/request_profiler.git"

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby on Rails console should show you which partials are taking a while to render. If that's not enough, you could install the new relic gem (https://github.com/newrelic/rpm) and use that in developer mode which will give you an overview of what's going on.

If you're deploying on [Heroku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) you can add the free version of rpm which will give you the same statistics on your running application.

Ruby has a profiler (http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/) which will show you memory usage, call times, etc., but it might be hard to disseminate your code from the framework code.

Comment: New Relic can tell you a little more but it doesn't have line-by-line code profiling which is necessary for full performance analysis.

Comment: and does not under windof

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with https://github.com/bhb/rack-perftools_profiler

It'll let you profile a single or multiple requests for any of cputime, methods, object allocations or walltime, and integrate nicely via Rack middleware.