# How to profile requests in a Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, request, profiler

How to profile requests in a Rails 3 application?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716418/how-can-i-profile-a-request-in-rails) seems to only work in 2.*. How should I do this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rack Mini Profiler is really good: https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby

Answer (score 9):

I usually use https://github.com/newrelic/rpm new relic. It tells you which is the slowest call on render and it also gives you which line in your code does just that. Very informative and easy to use.

Comment: thanks. I am trying this out. If you edit this answer I will be able to vote it up. Otherwise it is blocked.

Comment: why do you need me to edit it? anyway it is not a paid service. it is only paid if you use it for production. if you use it in dev mode it is entirely free. just access http://localhost:3000/newrelic

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [built in profiler?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html#profiler)

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer if it does not profile requests?

Comment: Because the built-in profiler might be used to profile requests.

Comment: fixed the link - waiting for peer review