# Is there anything inherently different in ruby 2.1.2 that would cause it to perform substantially worse than ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have an older app that is running on ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.17 - on passenger 4.  When I upgrade to ruby 2.1.2, the average transaction runs about 50% slower accross the board.  Can anyone think of any broad reasons to do with these different versions?  I have tried passenger, unicorn and puma, all with similar results.

Comment: None reasons I'm aware of, rather have an opposite experience. We've moved Rails 3.2.x based project from 1.9.3 to 2.1.x and got noticeable performance gains with about 10% increased memory consumption.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302346/how-to-profile-requests-in-a-rails-3-application

Comment: As it turns out there was an additional code change as part of the migration that caused most of the slowing.  Once we fixed that, we saw almost a 30% improvement! The tuning suggested in the answer provided about 10% of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been some issues related to memory consumption in Ruby 2+ that were not present in 1.9. It's possible that memory churn and frequent garbage collection could be making your application run more slowly. Take a look at http://www.omniref.com/blog/blog/2014/03/27/ruby-garbage-collection-still-not-ready-for-production/ and the discussion on Hacker News from earlier this year (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7488233), as well as Sam Saffron's response: http://samsaffron.com/archive/2014/04/08/ruby-2-1-garbage-collection-ready-for-production.

Comment: That's some outdated info, most of GC issues were fixed in 2.1.2 .

Comment: Even though these issues were supposed to be fixed in Ruby 2.1.2, I found that using RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR=1.3 and switching back to passenger fixed the performance problems I was seeing.  I attempted to dig deeper but after many hours on this, had to call it a day.  Thanks!